# Terracotta and shiro

Tags: shiro, terracotta

I want to use terracotta + Shiro in order to implement SSO. When I try to test it, I have the error:

```
    The configuration data in the base configuration from server at 'localhost:9510' does not obey the Terracotta schema:
    [0]: Line 4, column 5: Expected elements 'tc-properties servers clients' instead of 'system' here in element tc-config@http://www.terracotta.org/config
    [1]: Line 16, column 13: Expected elements 'offheap authentication http-authentication data-backup tsa-port jmx-port tsa-group-port security' instead of 'statistics' here in element server
    [2]: Line 19, column 13: Expected elements 'offheap authentication http-authentication data-backup tsa-port jmx-port tsa-group-port security' instead of 'dso-port' here in element server
    [3]: Line 21, column 13: Expected elements 'offheap authentication http-authentication data-backup tsa-port tsa-group-port security' instead of 'l2-group-port' here in element server
    [4]: Line 32, column 13: Expected elements 'offheap http-authentication data-backup tsa-port tsa-group-port security' instead of 'dso' here in element server
    [5]: Line 50, column 9: Expected elements 'server mirror-group update-check garbage-collection restartable client-reconnect-window' instead of 'mirror-groups' here in element servers
    [6]: Line 63, column 9: Expected elements 'server mirror-group update-check garbage-collection restartable client-reconnect-window' instead of 'ha' here in element servers
    [7]: Line 86, column 5: Element not allowed: application in element tc-config@http://www.terracotta.org/config
```

Could anyone helps me to find what's wrong?

Here is my configuration:

ehcache.xml on the tc client:

```
<ehcache  name="Plugin_Ehcache"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd"
     updateCheck="false" monitoring="autodetect"
     dynamicConfig="false">

<diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir/shiro-ehcache"/>

<defaultCache
        maxElementsInMemory="10000"
        eternal="false"
        timeToIdleSeconds="120"
        timeToLiveSeconds="120"
        overflowToDisk="false"
        diskPersistent="false"
        diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="120">
    <terracotta/>
</defaultCache>
<cache name="shiro-activeSessionCache"
       maxElementsInMemory="10000"
       eternal="true"
       timeToLiveSeconds="0"
       timeToIdleSeconds="0"
       diskPersistent="false"
       overflowToDisk="false"
       diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="600">
    <terracotta/>
</cache>    

<terracottaConfig url="localhost:9510"/>     
</ehcache>
```

tc-config.xml on the tc server

```
<tc:tc-config xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.terracotta.org/schema/terracotta-8.xsd" 
          xmlns:tc="http://www.terracotta.org/config" 
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<tc-properties>
<property name="l2.l1reconnect.enabled" value="true"/>
<property name="l2.l1reconnect.timeout.millis" value="5000"/>
<property name="sigar.enabled" value="false"/>
<property name="search.use.commit.thread" value="false"/>
<property name="search.lucene.use.ram.directory" value="true"/>
<property name="search.query.wait.for.txns" value="false"/>
<property name="logging.maxLogFileSize" value="100"/>
<property name="logging.maxBackups" value="10"/>
</tc-properties>

<system>
 <configuration-model>development</configuration-model>
</system> 

  <servers>
    <server host="localhost" name="Terracotta Server1">
      <!-- Specify the path where the server should store its data. -->
            <data>C:\Program Files\Terracotta\terracotta-3.7.5\server\server-data</data>
            <logs>C:\Program Files\Terracotta\terracotta-3.7.5\server\server-logs</logs>
            <index>C:\Program Files\Terracotta\terracotta-3.7.5\server\server-index</index>
            <statistics>C:\Program Files\Terracotta\terracotta-3.7.5\server\server-statistics</statistics>

       <!-- Specify the port where the server should listen for client 
       traffic. -->
         <dso-port bind="127.0.0.1">9510</dso-port>
         <jmx-port  bind="127.0.0.1">9520</jmx-port>
          <l2-group-port bind="localhost">9530</l2-group-port>
          <!--jmx-port bind="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx">9520</jmx-port>
       <tsa-port>9510</tsa-port>

       <tsa-group-port>9530</tsa-group-port-->
       <!-- Enable BigMemory on the server. -->
       <!--offheap>
         <enabled>true</enabled>
         <maxDataSize>4g</maxDataSize>
       </offheap-->

     <authentication/> 

       <dso>
    <client-reconnect-window>120</client-reconnect-window>
    <persistence>
      <mode>permanent-store</mode>
           <!--mode>temporary-swap-only</mode-->
            <!--<offheap>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
        <maxDataSize>450m</maxDataSize>
      </offheap>-->
    </persistence>
    <garbage-collection>
      <enabled>true</enabled>
      <verbose>false</verbose>
      <interval>300</interval>
    </garbage-collection>
  </dso>

     </server>

      <mirror-groups>
   <mirror-group group-name="group1">
     <members>
       <member>Terracotta Server1</member>
     </members>
     <ha>
       <mode>networked-active-passive</mode>
       <networked-active-passive>
         <election-time>5</election-time>
       </networked-active-passive>
     </ha>
    </mirror-group>
 </mirror-groups>     
 <ha>
   <mode>networked-active-passive</mode>
   <networked-active-passive>
     <election-time>5</election-time>
   </networked-active-passive>
 </ha>

      <update-check>
  <enabled>false</enabled>
</update-check>

    <!-- Add the restartable element for Fast Restartability (optional). -->
    <!--restartable enabled="true"/-->
  </servers>
  <clients>
    <logs>logs-%i</logs>
  </clients>
</tc:tc-config>
```

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Terracotta libraries are you using ? The tc-config.xml has some updated tags in 4.x version onwards. Please make sure the tc-config and ehcache xml obeys the schema.

Cheers,
Ridhav

Answer (score 0):

I saw you tried to use the mirror-group tag in your tc config, but it seems you misplaced it.

For example, this config should work :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<tc:tc-config xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.terracotta.org/schema/terracotta-8.xsd"
              xmlns:tc="http://www.terracotta.org/config"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <tc-properties>
    <property name="l2.l1reconnect.enabled" value="true"/>
    <property name="l2.l1reconnect.timeout.millis" value="5000"/>
    <property name="sigar.enabled" value="false"/>
    <property name="search.use.commit.thread" value="false"/>
    <property name="search.lucene.use.ram.directory" value="true"/>
    <property name="search.query.wait.for.txns" value="false"/>
    <property name="logging.maxLogFileSize" value="100"/>
    <property name="logging.maxBackups" value="10"/>
  </tc-properties>

  <servers>
    <mirror-group group-name="group1">
      <server host="localhost" name="Terracotta Server1">
        <!-- Specify the path where the server should store its data. -->
        <data>C:\Program Files\Terracotta\terracotta-3.7.5\server\server-data</data>
        <logs>C:\Program Files\Terracotta\terracotta-3.7.5\server\server-logs</logs>
        <index>C:\Program Files\Terracotta\terracotta-3.7.5\server\server-index</index>
        <!--<statistics>C:\Program Files\Terracotta\terracotta-3.7.5\server\server-statistics</statistics>-->

        <!-- Specify the port where the server should listen for client
        traffic. -->
        <tsa-port>9510</tsa-port>
        <jmx-port>9520</jmx-port>
        <tsa-group-port>9530</tsa-group-port>

        <authentication/>

      </server>
    </mirror-group>

    <update-check>
      <enabled>false</enabled>
    </update-check>

    <!-- Add the restartable element for Fast Restartability (optional). -->
    <!--restartable enabled="true"/-->
  </servers>
  <clients>
    <logs>logs-%i</logs>
  </clients>
</tc:tc-config>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this line that defines the schema used to construct your xml configuration file:

```
<tc:tc-config xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.terracotta.org/schema/terracotta-8.xsd
```

Enter the address provided and take a look at how nested xml elements and attributes are allowed to be used.

For instance, element dso-port is allowed in terracotta-6.xsd and terracotta-7.xsd, but not in the terracotta-8.xsd, which is the one you declared.

By the way, depending on the version of terracotta server you use, the appropriate xml schema should be declared due to element incompatibilities.